# Microsoft Azure Directory oAuth redirect_uri not accepting state query parameter

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to implement the oAuth flow to sign in with Microsoft.
I have the following endpoints:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

My flow is like this:
Redirect to Microsoft by clicking on Sign in with Microsoft button:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope=user.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F1%2Ffrontend%2Flogin%3Fstate%3Dtest
```

My redirect url is:

```
http://localhost:8000/1/frontend/login?state=test
```

Which is appended with the code I receive back from Microsoft.

I then perform a POST request to the /token endpoint.
However, I receive an error (AADSTS50011) saying:

```
AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:
```

The data I send is correct, except for the redirect_uri. I have the following value:

```
http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F1%2Ffrontend%2Flogin%3Fstate%3Dtest
```

Which is just an url encoded version of my redirect url including the ?state=test

I know that everything works fine, except the redirect_uri, because when I remove the state query param, everything works fine.
However, to route the redirect_uri correctly in my application, I need the state param.
I cannot add it in my App settings, and I have to include it in the first request (/authorize endpoint)
That all works fine, but the second (/token) POST request fails, I cannot enter my redirect_uri with the ?state= parameter.
I've tried several options such as encoding the redirect_uri, but it doesn't help.

All other oAuth flows (Like Github) are working fine. Except Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Attach your state param to the auth request itself, don’t put it in the redirect_uri param. Then the state param is automatically sent back to the redirect uri.

[https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope=user.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F1%2Ffrontend%2Flogin&state=xyz](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=%7Bclient_id%7D&scope=user.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F1%2Ffrontend%2Flogin&state=xyz)